# Get tables from Wiki that match specific text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wiki

I'm quite new to Python and BeautifulSoup, and I've been trying to work this out for several hours...

Firstly, I want to extract all table data from below link with "general election" in the title:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlow%E2%80%93Kilkenny_(D%C3%A1il_constituency)

I do have another dataframe with names of each table (eg. "1961 general election", "1965 general election"), but am hoping to get away with just searching for "general election" on each table to confirm if it's what I need.

I then want to get all the names that are in Bold (which indicates they won) and finally I want another list of "Count 1" (or sometimes 1st Pref) in the original order, which I want to compare to the "Bold" list.  I haven't even looked at this piece yet, as I haven't gotten past the first hurdle.

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlow%E2%80%93Kilkenny_(D%C3%A1il_constituency)"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
my_tables = soup.find_all("table", {"class":"wikitable"})
for table in my_tables:
    rows = table.find_all('tr', text="general election")
    print(rows)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, try to focus on one problem and also explain the output of the code you have so far, and why it isn't what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page requires some gymnastics, but it can be done:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

req = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlow%E2%80%93Kilkenny_(D%C3%A1il_constituency)')
soup = bs(req.text,'lxml')
#first - select all the tables on the page
tables = soup.select('table.wikitable')

for table in tables:        
    ttr = table.select('tbody tr')
    #next, filter out any table that doesn't involve general elections
    if "general election" in ttr[0].text: 
        #clean up the rows
        s_ttr = ttr[1].text.replace('\n','xxx').strip()
        #find and clean up column headings
        columns = [col.strip() for col in s_ttr.split('xxx') if len(col.strip())>0 ]
        rows = [] #initialize a list to house the table rows
        for c in ttr[2:]:
        #from here, start processing each row and loading it into the list
            row = [a.text.strip() if len(a.text.strip())>0 else 'NA' for a in  c.select('td')  ]
            if (row[0])=="NA":
                row=row[1:]
            columns = [col.strip() for col in s_ttr.split('xxx') if len(col.strip())>0 ]
            if len(row)>0:
                rows.append(row)
        #load the whole thing into a dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
        print(df)
```

The output should be all the general election tables on the page.

Comment: Yep - that looks great.  Thanks very much for your help Jack